# Recurrence relation related to integer partition

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recurrence-relations, integer-partitions

I have to prove a recurrence relation which is given by:

$p_{(n,S)} = \displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{s} \rfloor}$${p_{(n − st , S-\{s\})}}$

assuming that $\{s\}$ is an arbitrary fixed element of $S$.

(We assume that $p_{(0,S')}$ is to be equal to $1$ for any $S'$ and  $p_{(m,S')}$ is  equal to $0$ for any
negative $m$ and every $S'$.)

so at last $p_{(n,S)}$ is the integer partition of $n$ from the set of allowed elements $S$. I read about integer partition and young's diagram and even went through some videos reagrading how we can construct a generating function for $p_{(n)}$ but I am unable to prove this recurrence relation. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is proved by breaking up the partitions counted by $p(n,S)$ based on the number of occurrences of $s$.

Comment: What is the $s$ on the upper bound of the sum? I mean like as far as I got out, $s$ is a random element from the set $S$, what does $\frac{n}{s}$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an elaboration on Mike Earnest's comment and a slightly more formal statement of your claim.

For $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and any $s \in S$,
$$ p(n,S) = \sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor n/s \rfloor} p(n-ts,S \setminus \{s\}).$$

Proof: A partition of $n$ included in the count $p(n,S)$ has some number of parts $s$ and the other parts come from $S \setminus \{s\}$.  More explicitly, if $s$ occurs exactly $t$ times in $\lambda \vdash n$, then removing those $t$ copies of $s$ from $\lambda$ leaves a partition of $n-ts$ with parts from $S \setminus \{s\}$.  There are $p(n-ts,S \setminus \{s\})$ of the "leftover" partitions.  Note that $t$ can vary from 0 (i.e., $\lambda$ contains no part $s$) to $\lfloor n/s \rfloor$ (the maximal possible number of parts $s$).